Hystric Thread Pool is creating new database connection for each DB requests
I am using springboot application talking to mysql database. I have also enabled hystrix threadpool in it.
1 API requests is making 10 db requests.
Now since i have hystrix threadpool enabled, 1 http thread comes and uses 1 hystrix thread from the hystrix threadpool.
Now this hystrix thread is creating 10 new database requests. I wanted it should create only 1 database connection and talk to db 10 times and then release the connection.
May I know why hystrix thread is creating new database connection 10 times for the same thread?
I have tried hystrix semaphore which will use the http thread and creates only 1 db connection for 10 db request.
But I cant leverage the benefits of hystrix threadpool this way.
